# Dismissible stop swipe after certain width is reached

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, frontend

In my flutter project,
i have a listview with dismissable items. i wanted to create a ui such that if i swipe the list element from right to left it will getshift (swiped) 1/3 to left of the screen & in that 1/3rd space which was uncovered after swipe a cta will be present and that will have click action to open a bottomsheet.

how can i achieve such ui?

right now i've tried to manipulate various property of the dismissable widget provided by flutter but i wan't able to achive a similar output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the package `flutter_swipe_action_cell`. Add it to your project by running `flutter pub add flutter_swipe_action_cell` in your terminal.

Then you could something like this to display the items:

```
final items = List.generate(10, (index) => "Item $index");

  void openMyBottomSheet(int itemIndex) {
    // replace this with your logic to open your bottom sheet
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text("Hello World, Item $itemIndex!"),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => SwipeActionCell(
          /// this key is necessary
          key: ObjectKey(items[index]),
          trailingActions: <SwipeAction>[
            SwipeAction(
              title: "Open",
              onTap: (CompletionHandler handler) {
                openMyBottomSheet(index);
                // make sure to call the handler to close the swipe action
                handler(false); // true will dismiss the item from the list and false will keep it
              },
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ],
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The code is tested and fully functional. Note, that you can completely customize the swipe actions to your liking :)

Feel free to reach out if you need any more help with implementing this solution :))